# Returning to "sender" from a future inside an actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I want to do something like this -

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
....
override def receive = {
  case msg =>
     .... // do something
     Future {
       ... // calculate response
       sender ! response
     }
}
}

// in some other code -
val future = myActorRef ? msg
future.onSuccess {
    ....
}
```

Would this work? In other words, does Akka's "ask" implementation care if the response was sent back before the "receive" method finishes or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it would work, and there is even a built-in akka pattern for it - `pipe`:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

override def receive = {
  case msg =>
    .... // do something
    Future {
      ... // calculate response
      response
    } pipeTo sender()
}
```

There are, however some caveats in your code you should note:

`sender` is a function, therefore, when the code inside your `Future{...}` block executes, the actor may be handling a message from another sender, so you may reply to the wrong sender. To avoid this, evaluate your sender outside the closure:

```
val mySender = sender()
Future {
  ... // calculate response
  mySender ! response
}
```

You don't however need to worry about this if you use `pipe`.

---

You are wrapping a future into an actor and calling that actor with `ask`, which again gives you a future. You should really consider calling the future directly, without actors.
If you really need the actor, e.g. because you're isolating some mutable state or message ordering is important, you should be aware that computing the `Future` will not happen on the actor's thread, so you are losing your state consistency and message ordering - another reason to consider losing the actor, and calling the future directly.

Comment: Usually I won't go for a future inside an actor (where actor does almost nothing). But in my case I am dependent on another library which can send messages only to an actor (and that also as an ask). Hence the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `sender` may no longer be valid, when the future is performed. You have a couple of options, here are two from the top of my head:

You can *capture* the `sender` before the future:

```
override def receive = {
  case msg =>
     .... // do something
     val replyTo = sender

     Future {
       ... // calculate response
       replyTo ! response
     }
}
```

Or you can use the *pipeTo* pattern:

```
override def receive = {
  case msg =>
     .... // do something
     import akka.pattern.pipe

     Future {
       ... // calculate response
     }.pipeTo(sender())
}
```